# Foxit virtual PDF printer

Tags: windows, printing, print-server, shared-printers

I installed Foxit PDF virtual printer on my server to create an unattended PDF virtual printer (it saves to a given directory). I shared such virtual printer.
When I print directly from the server everything is fine. When I use the shared printer from other PC I don't get the file to the server directory, instead I get a save as.. popup asking me where to save my file.

Instead, I'd like to save to the same server diretory even when printing from a remote PC

Do Foxit virtual printer can do it? Do I need to change software? If so which one do you think is the best for such a scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using PDFCreator which:

- print silently to pdf file
- save the file on the server

http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Print&Share as your virtual printer for this with a File Printer channel to create PDF files.
See www.printandshare.info